# best way to archive files without compression

Tags: python, linux, zip, tar

When I'm trying to archive a lot of files (around 5000 files / 7GB), it takes a lot of time.
I've tried several methods but all of them take around 1:40 including `pigz`

`tar --use-compress-program="pigz -0 --recursive | pv" -cf rec.tar tar/` - takes 1:20

`tar cf - tar/ >  test.tar` - takes around 1:30

`zip -r -0 reg.zip tar` - around 2 minutes

I have 4 cores in my server and 16GB of ram

I've also tried to use python `ZipFile` module and tarfile module

Comment: [Does this answer your question ?][1]


  [1]: https://superuser.com/questions/299115/what-is-the-fastest-compression-method-for-a-large-number-of-files

Comment: I mean, I don't know what you're expecting, a magic bullet in compression? Compressing takes time, you can store it in a archive with no compression and that will be pretty fast.  `7za a -m0=Copy tar.7z tar/`

Comment: You might be able to go faster if you try doing your work in `/dev/shm`?

Comment: @Torxed I'm looking for the fastest way to add files into an archive without compression

Comment: The mine and EXODIA's answers should help.